# How does this headless fish still move?

Tags: anatomy, ichthyology

There is a [(VIDEO)](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10153414064599303&fref=nf) on Facebook where the fish starts to flail around despite no heart or internal organs.

What causes the fish to flail around the way it does?

My theories:

- It is because of pressure causing the muscles to contract - much like when you leave your own hand loose and squeeze up your arm making your fingers curl.
- It is because the nerves are still alive - much like how you can rub the fish heart the right way and cause it to beat again even though the fish is very much dead. (I watched my fifth-grade teacher do this in class)

Comment: I had actually heard a research talk related to this. It happens because of spinal reflex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [widely known spinal reflex arc](http://www.acnr.co.uk/11%20MA12/25_ACNRMA12_motor%20control.pdf) which causes decapitated animals (even soldier without head) to move over some period of time after decapitation.

One of the arc representations:

[image]

see also [The life after decapitation](http://www.toptenz.net/top-10-cases-life-decapitation.php)

[additional video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3teflb1QNN4)